# Expected Shortfall derivation

Tags: probability, integration, statistics

I am currently facing a problem of deriving the expected shortfall of the standard normal distribution. I have got the full derivation outlined however I am not sure about all the steps.

$ES=\frac{1}{1-\alpha} \int_{\alpha}^{1} \Phi^{-1}(u)du = \frac{1}{1-\alpha} \int_{\Phi^{-1}(\alpha)}^{\infty} s \phi(s)ds=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}[-\phi(s)]^{\infty}_{\Phi^{-1}(\alpha)}=\frac{\phi(\Phi^{-1}(\alpha))}{1-\alpha}$

I realize that in order to go from first part to second we need to employ change of variable. I use $s=\Phi^{-1}$ but then it doesn't follow such that I get exactly the second part.

Moreover, I am not sure what happens with $s$ when we do the integration such that we have only $-\phi(s)$ left. I have a hint that we use $\phi'(s)=s\phi(s)$ but I cannot recall that property from statistics/probability theory classes.

I will be most grateful if you could elaborate further on those two steps.

Comment: Let $s = \Phi^{-1}(u)$. When $u \to 1$, $s \to +\infty$; $u = \alpha$, $s = \Phi^{-1}(\alpha)$; $u = \Phi(s) \Rightarrow du = \phi(s)ds$. So these are the transformation details. To verify/understand the hint, you just write out the full functional form with the exponential and do a differentiation once by yourself, which is fairly simple.